# Rust: returning trait object in default method implementation

Tags: rust

When trying to return a trait object from a default implementation within a trait, such as

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        self
    }
}
```

the Rust compiler complains that

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Foo`
```

The type cast should be from `Box<Self>` to `Box<dyn Foo>`, why would this require Self to be sized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to convert an unsized type to trait object, since this will force it to have two sets of metadata at once.

Consider this code:

```
trait Foo: 'static {
    fn foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        self
    }
}

trait Bar {}

impl Foo for dyn Bar {}

impl Foo for i32 {}

impl<T> Bar for T {}

fn main() {
    let boxed = Box::new(42);
    boxed.foo();

    let boxed: Box<dyn Bar> = Box::new(42);
    boxed.foo();
}
```

In this case, there's nothing which would forbid the last call - all the signatures allow it. But, if we coerce `Box<dyn Bar>` to `Box<dyn Foo>`, where would the virtual functions table for `dyn Bar` go? (It's empty in this case, of course, but it still have to exist - empty traits are not special)

If you add `where Self: Sized` to `foo`, however, the last call is properly rejected:

```
error: the `foo` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
  --> src/main.rs:20:11
   |
2  |     fn foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Foo> where Self: Sized {
   |                                                         ----- this has a `Sized` requirement
...
20 |     boxed.foo();
   |           ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I think after also reading up a bit more on DSTs (https://runrust.miraheze.org/wiki/Dynamically_Sized_Type) this is starting to make sense. If I understand this correctly, references to unsized types are "fat pointers" containing additional meta-data (a virtual table reference or a size value for slizes), so converting that into a trait object would require two sets of meta-data (as you said) for a "double-fat" pointer, which could quickly get out of hand. So rather than supporting arbitrarily fat pointers, Rust simply prevents this.